# Why didn't the value of x change when the condition is true?

Tags: c++

```
int x = 1;
if (x > 0)
    int x = 2;
cout << x;
```

I expected the output would to be `2` because the condition is true, but what happens here?

I received `1` as output.

Comment: The `x` under the `if` is a different variable than the one above it. Remove the type qualifier from it. Just use `x = 2;`.

Answer (score 10):

You've [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable. 
This occurs when a variable declared within one scope has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

Making this modification will give the output you expect:

```
int x = 1;
if (x > 0) {
  x = 2; // now you're modifying the same x
}
cout << x;
```

Answer (score 4):

In c++ variable or other symbol declarations are local to their scope, redeclaring them in a different scope is called [*shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), and you will see no effect of the assignment outside of your current [*scope*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) level. This concerns

- Local scope (everything within braces `{}` or immediately appearing after a control flow statement like `if`, `else`, `case`, `while` or `for`)
  Typical examples:

  ```
  int i = 5;
  if(i == 5)
      int i = 2; // Single statement scope following the if
                 // Changes the local variable's value
  ```

  ---

  ```
  int j = 42;
  if(j == 42) {
      int j = 2; // Scoped block local variable
                 // Changes the local variable's value
  }
  ```
- Class scope (any class member variables)
  Typical examples:

  ```
  class MyClass {
      int myMember_;
  public:
      MyClass(int aValue) {
          int myMember_; // another local variable in the constructor function
          myMember_ = aValue; // Changes the local variable's value
      }
  };
  ```

  ---

  ```
  class MyClass {
      int myMember_;
  public:
      MyClass(int aValue) {
          int myMember_ = aValue; // Changes the local variable's value
      }
  };
  ```
- Namespace scope (any namespace global variables).
  Same principle as above. Namespaces can shadow variables (symbols) from other namespaces

---

Your c++ compiler should probably give you a warning about the appearance of one of the above mentioned situations.
With specifically GCC (g++) you can force that using the `-Wshadow` compiler flag.

Comment: I am glad you felt motivated enough to post an answer :) I wasn't.

Comment: @RSahu Well, I felt I could profit to use that as canonical dupe in the future. What I found about that problem that is asked frequently, was just too poor. ;-)

Comment: @RSahu As soon I'll reach rep cap with that answer, I'll mark it as _community wiki_, I'm honest. ;-)